# Javascript want to push objects into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push objects into array (mainArr) in JS. Below is my code:

```
var object = {1: 15, 2: 30};
var mainArr = ['settingsData'];

var values = Object.values(object);
var final = [];
var counter = 0;
var portion = {};

for (var key in object) {
  if (counter !== 0 && counter % 1 === 0) {
    final.push(portion);
    mainArr.push(portion)
    portion = {};
  }
  portion[key] = values[counter];
  counter++
}
final.push(portion);
mainArr.push(portion)
console.log(mainArr)
```

I see the output in the console like: `["settingsData", {1: 15}, {2: 30}]`

But I want the output like:

{ "settingsData":[{"1":"4"},{"2":"3"}] }

Comment: Your desired output is not an array, it's an object containing an array. Change the initial value of `mainArr` then push to the array property.

Comment: Create a new object to start with: `let main = {"settingsData": []};`, then push to `main.settingsData.push({1:15});`

Comment: @Stuart Can you plz reply this as the answer?

Comment: why do you use a such complicated approach to map entries?

Comment: @NinaScholz The backend API need the data in this manner.

Comment: Small comment (not related to the main issue): `counter % 1 === 0` is always true, for any positive integer. Remove that condition- it's trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, this would work:

```
var object = {1: 15, 2: 30};
var mainArr = {'settingsData': []};

var values = Object.values(object);
var final = [];
var counter = 0;
var portion = {};

for (var key in object) {
  if (counter !== 0 && counter % 1 === 0) {
    final.push(portion);
    mainArr.push(portion)
    portion = {};
  }
  portion[key] = values[counter];
  counter++
}
final.push(portion);
mainArr.settingsData.push(portion)
console.log(mainArr)
```

EDIT: (Explanaition added as asked in comments)

What you were doing is push each element into the already existing array containing `['settingsData']`. But what you were doing was to add items to the array located in the key `settingsData`.

So the changes were to set `mainArr` as an object containing field `settingsData` with an empty array as value, this is done on `const mainArr = { settingData: []}`

Then the push was done over the array contained in `settingsData` with `mainArr.settingsData.push(newValue)`.

If you need further explanaition just ask.

Comment: Nothing, it was intact

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara The comment was/is for Bastian. _"This would work"_ is a terrible "answer" as it doesn't explain what the problem with your approach is, and how Bastians answer fixes the problem.

Comment: I'll add an explanaition

Answer (score 1):

You could map single key/value pairs as new entry.

```js
var object = { 1: 15, 2: 30 },
    settingData = Object.entries(object).map(keyValue => Object.fromEntries([keyValue])),
    result = { settingData };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer has already been accepted, but OP did request i put my comment as an answer.

This simplifies your approach drastically:

```
// Create a new object to start with: 
let main = {"settingsData": []};

// Then push to the inner array:
main.settingsData.push({1:15});
```